# Static NSDate variable keeps resetting between function calls

Tags: ios, swift, static, nsdate

I'm trying to keep track of how much time a user spends in one of my ViewControllers. I'm doing this by first creating a TimeManager struct with a static NSDate variable, like so:

```
struct TimeManager {
    static var timeStamp: NSDate!
    static let globalManager = TimeManager()

    func setSessionDuration(startupTime: NSDate, controller: String) {
        let timeInterval = ( (startupTime.timeIntervalSinceNow) * -1)
        LocalUser.user.timePerController[controller]! += timeInterval
    }  
}
```

Then, in my ViewController's "viewDidLoad" method, I set the "timeStamp" variable of my TimeManager to be a newly-initialized NSDate() :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    LocalUser.user.mostRecentAction = "Browsed Item Feed."
    TimeManager.timeStamp = NSDate()
    print("\(TimeManager.timeStamp)")
    ...
```

Finally, in "viewWillDisappear", I call my "setSessionDuration" function and pass it the "timeStamp" I had set when the view loaded:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    print("\(TimeManager.timeStamp)")
    TimeManager.globalManager.setSessionDuration(TimeManager.timeStamp, controller: "BrowseViewController")
    ...
```

However, through print statements I've discovered that the "timeStamp" variable resets to the current time when I pass it to the function, for whatever reason:

[image]

I set a timer on my iPhone to 3 minutes and switched to a different view controller at the 3 minute mark, so I can see that whats happening is the "timeStamp" is being reset to whatever time I'm calling "viewWillDisappear". I'm at a bit of a loss here- can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `inout` in your function `setSessionDuration` startupTime Argument:

```
 func setSessionDuration(inout startupTime: NSDate, controller: String) {
    let timeInterval = ( (startupTime.timeIntervalSinceNow) * -1)
    LocalUser.user.timePerController[controller]! += timeInterval
}
```

And in `viewWillDisappear` change `TimeManager.timeStamp` to `&TimeManager.timeStamp` to pass it by reference:

```
TimeManager.globalManager.setSessionDuration(&TimeManager.timeStamp, controller: "BrowseViewController")
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use "inout" with a immutable variable (NSDate)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you also set TimeManager.timeStamp = NSDate() in some other place in your code ?

Another possible cause could be that you are performing a segue to the same view controller (rather than closing it) and the value you are seeing is the one from the second instance's viewDidLoad.   You could print the function name in each place along with the time stamp to make sure this is the case or not.

Comment: i set the TimeManager.timeStamp in all my other view controllers in very much the same fashion (haven't done it yet but thats the plan) so that I can have a session duration for each, but I'm pretty sure that between BrowseViewController loading and disappearing, I don't reset it.